# Why have emails from "Favorite Tags" subscription stopped?

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, favorites-notifications, subscription

I am subscribed to my Favorite Tags for delivery every 15 minutes. I have not received any emails from that filter in 14 hours, although looking at the filter at StackExchange shows plenty of new questions. I continue to receive emails from other sources, so it's not a general failure of my email.

Is anybody else experiencing this?

Also, when I view the filter at StackExchange, there's an "edit" link that should let me change whether and how often I get emailed, but it does nothing.  (Tried Firefox 11.0 and Safari 5.15.)  I intended to toggle the frequency to see if that jump-started delivery.

Comment: OK, I started receiving the emails again an hour ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bug prevented filter subscription emails from going out for the past 15 hours. It's been fixed, so emails are being sent again. Sorry about that.